# When is using instance variables more advantageous than using let()?

Tags: variables, rspec

There seems to be a lot of support for using [`let()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359558/when-to-use-rspec-let) in rspec to initialize variables. What are some cases for using instance variables (i.e. `@name`) instead?

Answer (score 14):

I always prefer let to an instance variable for a couple of reasons:

- Instance variables come into existence when they get referenced which
  meant that if you make any mistake in instance variable spelling then
  it would definitly lead you to some issues as a new instance variable
  is initialized to nil. But in let you will get NameError if you
  misspell it.
- Further you will be initializing the instance variables in before
  block, which means that before block will be executed every time a
  spec would run even if that spec dont use those instance variables
  you have initialized. example given below;

  ```
  before do
    @user  = Factory :user
    @movie = Factory :movie
  end

  it "should have user" do
    @user.should eq User.first
  end

  it "should have movie" do
    @movie.should eq Movie.first
  end
  ```

Although all the specs run fine but there is not use of `@movie` in first spec and no use of `@user` in second.

You can also use let with bang "!" `let!`, `let` is lazily evaluated and will never be instantiated if you don't call it, use `let` to define memoized helper , while `let!` is forcefully evaluated before each method call.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to say like this: at all points, `let` is preferable to instance variables and is always more advantageous than instance variables.

Answer (score 8):

I have favored this question, but at the end I am answering to the question myself.

First to describe the differences

The `let` method when used it does not initialize the variable until it is referenced in the test - which makes it different from `@instance variables` which are initialized from the start.

In general there is no big diffidence. Use `@instance variables` when you want be sure that `let` object is initialized. But on the other hand this can be done the same with `let!` , so there is no obvious reason for using `@instance variable`.

To conclude, to me, there is **obvious** reason to use `@instance variable` over `let`, but there is no obvious reason to use `@instance variables` over `let!`

`@instance variables` takes more time to load, and by using them, could lead to unwanted complexity in code which could be avoided by using `let` or `let!`

You can take a look at these two answers as well, maybe it will give you some more information:

[When to use RSpec let()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359558/when-to-use-rspec-let)

[RSpec: What is the difference between let and a before block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974360/rspec-difference-between-let-and-before-block)