# FactoryGirl Error "define_method': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Here is my Lesson Factory  i-e lesson.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lesson do |lesson|
   lesson.sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
   lesson.sequence(:description) { |n| "description#{n}" }
   lesson.sequence(:transcript) { |n| "transcript#{n}" }
   association :course, strategy: :build
  end
end
```

Here is my lesson_spec.rb file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Lesson do
  before { let(:lesson) { FactoryGirl.create(:lesson) } }
  subject (:lesson)
  it { should validate_presence_of :title    }
end
```

Any Help? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did i this way and it works

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Lesson do
  subject { FactoryGirl.create(:lesson) }
  it { should validate_presence_of :title    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the before statement in the before block.

```
before { let(:lesson) { FactoryGirl.create(:lesson) } }
```

change to this

```
let(:lesson) { FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple you dont needed let in before, either you would use `before` or `let` i would prefer to use let, have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116613/when-is-using-instance-variables-more-advantageous-than-using-let/14118197#14118197) answerexplainin when to use let and when to use before.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Lesson do
  let(:lesson) { FactoryGirl.create(:lesson) }
  subject (lesson)
  it { should validate_presence_of :title    }
end
```