# (apparently) identical tests for two rake tasks; only one passes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

I'm trying to write tests in rspec for two rake tasks which are defined in the same file (in a Rails 3.0.11 project). For some reason only one of them passes. I've written a small demo to abstract away the actual content of the tasks, and the same thing happens. Both tasks work when invoked with `rake` from the command line. What's going on? Here's my demo:

**lib/tasks/demo_tasks.rake**

```
namespace :demo do
  task :test => :environment do
    puts "test!"
  end

  task :test_two => :environment do
    puts "second test!"
  end
end
```

**spec/lib/tasks/demo_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rake'

describe "test tasks" do
  let(:rake) do
    app = Rake::Application.new
    app.options.silent = true
    app
  end

  before :each do
    Rake.application = rake
    Rake.application.rake_require 'lib/tasks/demo_tasks',
                                  [Rails.root.to_s]
    Rake::Task.define_task :environment
  end

  describe "demo:test" do
    it "runs" do
      rake["demo:test"].invoke
    end
  end

  describe "demo:test_two" do
    it "also_runs" do
      rake["demo:test_two"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

**rspec spec/lib/tasks/demo_spec.rb**

```
test tasks
  demo:test
test!
    runs
  demo:test_two
    also_runs (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) test tasks demo:test_two also_runs
     Failure/Error: rake["demo:test_two"].invoke
     RuntimeError:
       Don't know how to build task 'demo:test_two'
     # ./spec/lib/tasks/demo_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Nutshell:** Change your `before` to a `before :all` (instead of `:each`).

**Or:** Pass an empty array as a third parameter to `rake_require`.

```
Rake.application.rake_require 'lib/tasks/demo_tasks', 
                              [Rails.root.to_s], 
                              []
```

**Details**

```
def rake_require(file_name, paths=$LOAD_PATH, loaded=$")
  fn = file_name + ".rake"
  return false if loaded.include?(fn)
  ...
```

`$"` is a Ruby special variable that holds an array of modules loaded by `require`.

If you don't pass the optional parameter, `rake_require` will use that array of modules loaded by Ruby. This means the module won't be loaded again: Ruby knows the module was loaded, rake checks to see what Ruby knows, and it's a new rake instance for each test.

Switching to `before :all` worked because it meant the `let` block only ran once: one rake instance, one module load, everybody is happy.

All this said, why reload the rake environment twice anyway? Your goal is to test your tasks, which doesn't require a fresh rake context for every spec.

You could eliminate the local altogether at the cost of some minor verbosity in each spec:

```
describe "test tasks" do
  before :all do
    Rake.application = Rake::Application.new
    Rake.application.rake_require 'lib/tasks/demo_tasks', [Rails.root.to_s]
    Rake::Task.define_task :environment
  end

  describe "demo:test" do
    it "runs" do
      Rake::Task["demo:test"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

You could define an instance variable in the `before` block to avoid the `Rake::Task` reference:

```
before :all do
  @rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake.application = @rake
  Rake.application.rake_require 'lib/tasks/demo_tasks', [Rails.root.to_s]
  Rake::Task.define_task :environment
end

describe "demo:test" do
  it "runs" do
    @rake["demo:test"].invoke
```

IMO, less desirable for a number of reasons. [Here's a summary I agree with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359979/438992).

Comment: This does make both tests pass. But can you explain why?

Comment: @gregates Not entirely without more digging. My guess is that the second `rake_require` isn't loading the file because it was loaded once already, so the new task definitions are gone for the second test.

Comment: Cool. Well, thanks for the assistance. Still would like to understand this phenomenon better.

Comment: For reasons I don't understand, if you put the `require` etc.in `before :all`, and if you invoke the *same* task twice, the second invocation doesn't happen. Fortunately, the other suggestion works:  leave the `require` in `before :each` and use `[]` as the third parameter. Then the second invocation works.

Comment: Haven't tried with your example, but maybe using `execute` instead of `invoke` would make all your tasks to run. [invoke](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html#M000119) only runs the task if it consider it is necessary (don't ask me about the criteria used)

Answer (score 5):

A popular search engine led me here, as in my case I was seeing tests fail when `#invoke` was used more than once for a given test. The solution below builds on @dave-newtown's answer.

The problem arises because at the time of writing (Rake v12), `#invoke` runs a task *once only* so for example:

```rb
RSpec.describe "demo:test" do
  it "runs" do
    expect(SomethingWeAreInvoking).to eql(ProofIfWasInvoked)
    Rake::Task["demo:test"].invoke
  end

  it "runs" do
    expect(SomethingWeAreInvoking).to eql(ProofIfWasInvoked)
    Rake::Task["demo:test"].invoke
  end
end
```

...might pass for whichever `it` runs first if the test is well written and the task invokes correctly, but will always then fail for the second `it` as within a given `Rake.application`, the use of `#invoke` only ever runs a task once. The has-been-run-before state is apparently remembered inside the `Rake.application` instance.

Yes, this does mean that *at least under Rake v12* as tested, a lot of online articles showing how to test Rake tasks are (fo) incorrect, or get away with it because they only show a single test for any given task in their examples.

We could use Rake's `#execute`, but this doesn't run dependent tasks so causes its own set of problems and gets us even further away from testing the Rake stack as if it were invoked on the command line.

Instead, a hybrid of the accepted answer along with other bits and pieces from online yields this alternative:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rake'

RSpec.describe 'demo:test' do
  before :each do
    Rake.application = Rake::Application.new
    Rake.application.rake_require 'lib/tasks/demo_tasks', [Rails.root.to_s], []
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

  it 'runs' do
    expect(SomethingWeAreInvoking).to eql(ProofIfWasInvoked)
    Rake.application.invoke_task('demo.test')
  end

  it 'runs with a parameter' do
    expect(SomethingWeAreInvoking).to eql(ProofIfWasInvoked)
    Rake.application.invoke_task('demo.test[42]')
  end
end
```

- It prepares Rake on `before :each`.
- Each time, a new `Rake.application` is created; this means we can use `invoke` in any number of tests, albeit only once in any single test.
- If we just used the `Rake.application` out-of-the-box instance, we could just write `Rake.application.rake_require 'tasks/demo_tasks'` as all the paths etc. are set up, but since we definitely need a new Rake application instance for each test to avoid "dirtying" its state across tests, the "longhand" form from @dave-newtown is needed.
- I use `Rake.application.invoke_task` instead of `Rake::Task[...].invoke`. This puts the syntax for arguments on parity with that used on the Rake command line, which I feel is a more 'accurate' and natural way to test tasks that take args.

Yes, this does mean that *at least under Rake v12* as tested, a lot of online articles showing how to test Rake tasks are incorrect, or get away with it because they only show a single test for any given task in their examples. It's probable that earlier Rake versions didn't behave this way, so those articles were correct at the time they were written.

Hope someone finds this helpful.

> Reference articles:
>
> - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rake/Rake/Task#invoke-instance_method - clue is in 'Invoke the task *if it is needed*. Prerequisites are invoked first' (my emphasis)
> - Compare https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rake/Rake/Task#execute-instance_method - 'Execute the actions associated with this task', no mention of 'if needed' or prerequisites
> - Search engines yield articles such as https://medium.com/@sampatbadhe/rake-task-invoke-or-execute-419cd689c3bd
>
> (search engine hints: testing rake rspec test invoke invoked run only once)

Comment: Omg, I was doubting myself thinking all those online articles where falsey. Even found an article with two test examples, one being `expect(...).not_to have_received(...)` which obviously makes sense if the rake tasks is not executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Rake keeps track of which tasks have been run and assumes you only want to run them once. A simple solution is to call `#reenable` on the task in a `before(:each)` hook before invoking the task. Say for example that the rake task is supposed to call two methods on SomeClass and you want to test these in separate examples:

```rb
RSpec.describe Rake::Task['my_task'] do
  before do
    allow(SomeClass).to receive(:method1)
    allow(SomeClass).to receive(:method2)

    described_class.reenable
    described_class.invoke
  end

  it 'does a thing' do
    expect(SomeClass).to have_received(:method1)
  end

  it 'does another thing' do
    expect(SomeClass).to have_received(:method2)
  end
end
```