# ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy returns count of 1, but present? false in RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm testing with RSpec as follows, and my tests are telling me that I'm creating `ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy` objects that have a `count` of 1 for one test, but then return `present?` false on another test per below. Please note: `child` gets created in a :child_link `after_create` callback.

```
let(:link) { create(:child_link) }

it 'should have a child with ancestors class of X' do
  expect(link.child.ancestors.class).to be Stake::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
end
=> PASSES

it 'should have a child with ancestors (1)' do
  expect(link.child.ancestors.count).to eq(1)
end
=> PASSES

it 'should have a child with ancestors present' do
  expect(link.child.ancestors.present?).to be true
end
=> FAILS
```

Why does this test fail? RSpec just tells me that it returned false, not true. There's no error.

Here is my factory:

```
factory :kin_link do
  group
  stake
  visible true

  factory :child_link, :class => ChildLink do
  end
end
```

And here are my associations:

```
class KinLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stake, foreign_key: 'feather_id'
  belongs_to :group, foreign_key: 'tip_group_id'
end

class ChildLink < KinLink
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Stake', foreign_key: 'tip_id'

class AncestorLink < KinLink
  belongs_to :ancestor, class_name: 'Stake', foreign_key: 'tip_id'
end

class Stake < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :kin_links, foreign_key: 'feather_id'

  has_many :child_links, foreign_key: 'feather_id'
  has_many :children, through: :child_links

  has_many :child_links, foreign_key: 'feather_id'
  has_many :children, through: :child_links

  has_many :ancestor_links, foreign_key: 'feather_id'
  has_many :ancestors, through: :ancestor_links
```

When I do this, the test passes:

```
it 'should pass if I reload the :child_link object' do
  link2 = ChildLink.find(link.id)
  expect(link2.child.ancestors).to be_present
=> PASSES
```

Or this:

```
it 'should pass if I reload the :child_link object' do
  expect(link.child.reload.ancestors).to be_present
end
=> PASSES
```

Could it be that associations are cached somehow and that they need to be reloaded after the `after_create` happens for the ChildLink?

Playing around in my console sandbox seemed to confirm this: I can get the `has_many :through` association to work if I use `Stake.find` and then call `ancestors` on the result, but not if I call `child_link.child.ancestors`

```
child_link = FactoryGirl.create(:child_link) 
=> #<ChildLink id: 86...
child_link.child
=> #<Stake id: 84... 
child_link.child.ancestors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>          
Stake.find(84).ancestors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Stake id: 83...
```

Edited per comments to include things I have tried additionally:

- Using a let statement instead of `before(:each)`
- Testing each separately, each time after using `rake db:test:prepare`. Same results.

Comment: In some circumstances `.count` can reference a cached value, such as a counter cache. Does `expect(@child.ancestors).to eq([])` also fail? If not, `.count` may be referencing a cached value.

Comment: expect(@child.ancestors).to eq([]) passes. Hmm.. I feel like you're giving me a hint. I'm thinking about it. Thanks!

Comment: Prefer `let()` to instance variables. See this thread for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359558/when-to-use-rspec-let

Comment: Agree on using `let()` vs. instance variables. I wouldn't expect it to make a difference here, but worth considering. Although beware the difference between `let` and `let!`)

Comment: styling pedantry: try `expect(@child.ancestors).to be_present` ? or `expect(@child.ancestors.present?).to eq(true)` or `expect(@child.ancestors.present?).to be_truthy`

Comment: Things that might be helpful to add to your question: whether each test passes or fails the same way if run individually, even if you reset your test database beforehand; the definition of each association involved; the factory definition(s); the SQL run by the failing test.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've included some more info, including a strange result I get in the console, above. Same results. I don't know how to see the SQL in my test transactions. Any pointers there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `child` Stake object that gets created in the `after_create` callback as a result of `create(:child_link)` was running a `self.ancestors` query (in another callback). I had no idea that queries like these are cached. Thanks to everyone in the comments for pointing me in the right direction.