# When to use RSpec's let! instead of before?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have been told that it makes sense to use `let!()` instead of `before(:each)` block. However, I can't see much logic in doing that. Does it actually make any sense to make something like in the example below:

```
context 'my super context' do
  let!(:something) do
    Model.create(subject: "Hello", body: "World")
  end

  it '...' do
    # We never call something
    # All we want is just to evaluate and create the record
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that you won't call `something` anywhere in the example at all. Technically I don't see much difference between that and this, unless it's actually more strict and easy to understand without documentation just like plain English:

```
context 'my super context' do
  before(:each) do
    Model.create(subject: "Hello", body: "World")
  end

  it '...' do
    # We never call something
    # All we want is just evaluate and create the record
  end
end
```

Could someone help me to understand the idea behind the rule I was given? 
I can understand why you would use `let` instead of `before(:all)` and `before(:each)` with the variable inside. But here it just feels like they just blindly follow the phrase "use a let helper instead of a before block" found somewhere in the blog post.

Thank you very much!

Comment: As far as i am concerned let is lazy evaluated. A before will create all the records even if not referenced. The variables defined with let will be only evaluated if the were used later in your tests

Comment: The first answer here goes into some more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359558/when-to-use-rspec-let

Comment: @theDrifter "close as duplicate" :)

Comment: @Ven not really it is completely different question. **I am talking about `let!`** I know the difference between let, and why would you use it instead of before. There's the point. I don't understand the point to define `let!(:abcd) { Model.create() }` evaluate the code. It is gonna create the record, but never actually to call `abcd` later. I mean you could do that inside the block with the same luck. There's no difference at all, except the second example is clearer and more logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a best practice to always use `let!` rather than a `before` block. You're correct:

- If you want to run a block of code before every example, and you need that code to return a value, use `let!`.
- If you want to run a block of code before every example, but you don't need to pass a value from that code directly to your example, use `before`. (Using `let!` would mislead the reader into thinking that its value was being used.)

Note that both `let!` and `before` blocks should be used sparingly in any case. They create the risk of later test writers adding tests in the same block that don't need the result of the `let!` or `before`, making those tests harder to understand and slower.