# Testing interaction requests sequences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

There best practices is do not use `@instance` variables and use `let(:object)`. But how to write test of call sequences where each step require previous state but not clean state.

I'd like to write code like this:

```
describe "intearction" do
  let(:user1) { ... }
  let(:user2) { ... }

  it "request" do
    get "/api/v1/request", {user2}, token(user1)
    expect(...).to ...
  end

  it "confirm" do
    get "/api/v1/confirm", {user1}, token(user2)
    expect(...).to ...
  end
end
```

But that will not work. It may be worked only like this:

```
describe "intearction" do
  let(:user1) { ... }
  let(:user2) { ... }

  it "all tests" do
    # request
    get "/api/v1/request", {user2}, token(user1)
    expect(...).to ...
    # confirm
    get "/api/v1/confirm", {user1}, token(user2)
    expect(...).to ...
  end
end
```

The `it` become unusable and names of tests become comments or puts to console. The rspec subsystem loses its purpose. Using `@instance` variables is bad practice, is there any `let`-like definition function that does not create new plain variable per each test but per group of tests?

The sequences and api's exists not the first year. What is about your practice of testing sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tests when you need to prepare environment for the test you do it in `before` block. So here is how your tests might look like

```
describe "intearction" do
  let(:user1) { ... }
  let(:user2) { ... }

  describe '#request' do
    it "does something" do
      get "/api/v1/request", {user2}, token(user1)
      expect(...).to ...
    end
  end

  describe '#confirm' do
    context 'request was made before' do
      before { get "/api/v1/request", {user2}, token(user1) }

      it "does something as well" do
        get "/api/v1/confirm", {user1}, token(user2)
        expect(...).to ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```