# How to unit test a module (a resque scheduler job) in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, resque, resque-scheduler

I have a (simplified) module: (/app/jobs/checkpulse.rb)

```
module CheckPulse
  @queue = :heartbeat
  def self.perform()
    Machine.all.each do |machine|
      machine.update_columns(active_alarm: true) #do not want to touch updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

I can use it in the rails console and it changes all machines as expected.

I am trying to write a spec to test it:
(/spec/jobs/checkpulse_spec.rb)

```
require "spec_helper"
require_relative '../../app/jobs/checkpulse'

describe "CheckPulse" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:machine) { FactoryGirl.create(:machine, user: user, heartbeat_timeout: 5) }

  it "should change the machine to alarm mode" do
    CheckPulse.perform
    expect(machine.active_alarm).to be_true
  end
end
```

This test fails every time. I have used puts inside the CheckPulse module to check on it and it has the expected behaviour inside the module, but when it returns from the module, the machine has not changed.

I have tried [mixing the module into a dummy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542945/testing-modules-in-rspec/1546493#1546493), but that didn't work either. I also tried running rails console in the test environment to see if it was an environment problem, but the module worked fine there too.

I have spent the entire day on this, please help!

Comment: might be silly, but if you reload the `machine` (`machine.reload`) before doing the expectation, does it work? It is loading up the `machine` var before modifying its state in the db, so maybe it just needs a refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to follow ruby & rails conventions. If you call module `CheckPulse` it's file name should be `check_pulse.rb`. It will help you to avoid `require_relative`. Second, in spec and in module you interact with different ruby objects which are both writing to same row in database. And if you update one object another will not be updated synchronously. You need to reload it manually by calling `machine.reload` in spec.

Also few tips to your code:

- never use `all.each`. It will stuck if you have a 2k+ records in your database. For iterating all database records use `find_each`
- instead of loading each record and update it, you could update all records with `update_all` -> `Machine.update_all(:column_1 => value_1, :column_2 => value_3)`
- avoid round brackets in methods without arguments

Comment: expect(machine.reload.active_alarm).to be_true worked! Thanks! I also renamed the files and changed to self.perform - without (). Now looking into find_each.

Comment: changed to Machine.all.find_each do |machine| . So, is this the same as all.each as long as the number of records is less than the batch size (default 1000)?

Comment: Changed filename to check_pulse.rb and magically eliminated require_relative.