# Testing a module with RSpec 3

Tags: class, testing, methods, rspec, module

I was struggling with testing module's `def self.method`. I found a great thread [here with a very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542945/testing-modules-in-rspec#answer-19487957). My code is:

```
module MyModule
  def self.method
    groups = Posts.group :name
  end
end

describe Class.new { include MyModule } do
  its (:method) { should be_a(ActiveRecord::Relation) }
end
```

The problem is, that the question is about **including a module**, and **not extending** it. As the author of the answer mentioned, he **tested it with RSpec 2**. I tested it with **RSpec 3.0.0** and the only thing that worked was when the method was an instance's method. Otherwise I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `method' for #<#<Class:0x0000000..>:0x00000006..>
```

How can I test the `MyModule.method`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be getting an instance and class level method confused.
Try this to be sure it's really testing on the Class-level method

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule
end
it "should have an active relation on method" do
  expect(MyClass.method).to be_a(ActiveRecord::Relation)
end
```

Comment: With that precise setup I'm getting this error `undefined method 'method' for DummyClass:Class` :-/

Comment: right, so your include isn't doing what you think it's doing... which means that perhaps `include` is not what you want.

Comment: You're right. I'm upvoting this, thanks. I think my question is confusing. But how would you test a module's self method anyway?

Comment: The problem with modules is that they don't evaluate class methods the same way... I would normally use extend (not include) for the class methods in order for them to get into a class. or if I'm using Active Model I can use `included`  ...