# Testing Ruby Modules with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm having a bad time finding on SO/Google this particular case. I have a module with functions and in order to use them, you have to create a Class which includes/extends the Module depending if you'll want instance methods or class methods.

```
module A
  def say_hello name
    "hello #{name}"
  end

  def say_bye
    "bye"
  end
end
```

**How can I test this module using rspec?**

**I have something like this, and I'm not sure where is the point I should create the class and extend Module.**

```
describe A do
  class MyClass
    extend A
  end

  before(:each) { @name = "Radu" }

  describe "#say_hello" do
    it "should greet a name" do
      expect(Myclass.say_hello(@name)).to eq "hello Radu"
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your method doesn't return this value. You should check that it puts it, so that method `puts` called once with argument `hello Radu`

Comment: @zishe yep `say_hello(@name)` return `nil`.

Comment: This was an silly example. I have methods that return things. My concern is how to use extend in rspec

Comment: I edited the question to remove the misleading `puts`.

Comment: **Related**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542945/testing-modules-in-rspec

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create an anonymous class in your tests:

```
describe A do
  let(:extended_class) { Class.new { extend A } }
  let(:including_class) { Class.new { include A } }

  it "works" do
    # do stuff with extended_class.say_hello
    # do stuff with including_class.new.say_hello
  end
end
```

To see something similar in real code, I've used this strategy for [testing my attr_extras lib](https://github.com/barsoom/attr_extras/blob/master/spec/attr_private_spec.rb).

That said, `include` and `extend` are standard features of Ruby, so I wouldn't test that every module works both when including and when extending – that's usually a given.

If you create a named class in the test, like you do in your question, I believe that class will exist globally for the duration of your test run. So this class will leak between every test of your test suite, potentially causing conflicts somewhere.

If you use `let` to create an anonymous class, it will only be available inside this particular test. There is no global constant pointing to it that could conflict with other tests.

You could also use RSpec's [`stub_const`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants) to get a constant that doesn't leak, if you need to:

```
stub_const("MyClass", Class.new { … })
# do stuff with MyClass
```

Note that you'd run `stub_const` inside a `before` or `it`. Not just at the top of the file or in the class context.

Comment: I still get `undefined method `my_method' for #<Class:0x007fbcd68917d8>`, but perhaps is my fault. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: @radubogdan I tried pasting [this exact code (Gist link)](https://gist.github.com/henrik/8d400883a99779de4926) to an existing RSpec test and it passes, so maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: Yes, for sure something else is wrong, but I can't find what. Could be spec_helper? (I created spec_helper using rspec --init, rspec version is 3.1.7)

Comment: @radubogdan No idea, I'm afraid. Try removing/tweaking things and see if you can pinpoint the issue, and ask a separate question about it, perhaps?

Comment: If I replace `require 'spec_helper'` with `require_relative '../lib/a.rb'` is working good.

Comment: @radubogdan Aha. Yes, you need to require the tested class or module in your test file. If you're using Rails it may automatically do it for you in most cases, but that's not true for Ruby in general.

Answer (score 2):

To help out future readers, here's an example I got going using @henrik-n 's solution:

```
# slim_helpers.rb
module SlimHelpers

  # resourceToTitle converts strings like 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
  # to 'Auto Scaling Group'
  def resourceToTitle(input)
    input.split('::')[-1].gsub(/([A-Z])/, ' \1').lstrip
  end

end

# slim_helpers_spec.rb
require_relative '../slim_helpers'

describe SlimHelpers do

  # extended class
  let(:ec) { Class.new { extend SlimHelpers } }

  it "converts AWS resource strings to titles" do
    out = ec.resourceToTitle('AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup')
    expect(out).to eq 'Auto Scaling Group'
  end
end
```

Comment: You could also use `Class.extend(SlimHelpers)` if you need to test class methods.